# select only those who have no contact

Tags: sql, oracle

I updated my question.

I have table like this:

| id | name | contact |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 65489 |
| 1 | A |  |
| 1 | A | 45564 |
| 2 | B |  |

so, i want table like this:

| id | name | contact |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | B |  |

Comment: Please [edit] the question with a [MRE] including: the `CREATE TABLE` statement for your table; and the `INSERT` statements for your sample data as it makes a difference to the solutions whether your `contact` values are `NULL` or are a white-space padded string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using exists logic we can try:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t2
                  WHERE t2.id = t1.id AND t2.contact IS NOT NULL);
```

In plain English, the above query says to return any records for which we cannot find another record belonging to the same `id` group having a non `NULL` contact value.

Here is a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=87c198ab73be167ad1f57b7202bb7984) of the query.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT id,
       MAX(name) AS name
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(contact) = 0;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (id, name, contact) AS
SELECT 1, 'A', 3265489 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'A', NULL    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'A', 5645564 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'B', NULL    FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | ID | NAME |
> | --- | --- |
> | 2 | B |

---

Or, if you can have `contact` values that are strings padded with white-space then:

```
SELECT id,
       MAX(name) AS name
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(CASE LENGTH(TRIM(contact)) WHEN 7 THEN 1 END) = 0;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=3cbc8dd272847e11a674d6ae3075b09a)*

Answer (score 0):

Just as you would formulate it - select all `ID`s  that have no (`minus`) contact

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE ID in 
(select id from table_name
 minus
 select id from table_name where contact is not null)
```